# How to Clone FeedComment Along with FeedItem using .clone function?

Tags: apex, clone

I am trying to Clone the feedItem along with FeedComment. I was successfully able to clone feedItem but unable to clone the FeedComments. Below is the snippet

```
for (FeedItem feedRecord : feedItemList) {
     FeedItem clone = feedRecord.clone(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);
     clone.ParentId = cloneObj.Id;
     feedItemIdSet.add(feedRecord.Id);
     feedItemToCloneList.add(clone);
}
INSERT feedItemToCloneList;

    for (FeedComment feedComment : [SELECT Id, FeedItemId, ParentId, RelatedRecordId FROM FeedComment WHERE FeedItemId IN:feedItemIdSet]) {
                 FeedComment feedCommentClone = feedComment.clone(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);
                 feedCommentClone.ParentId = cloneObj.Id;
     }
```

I am getting this error : Field is not writeable: FeedComment.ParentId . I am aware the ParentId cannot be updated, but I am cloning the record first using .clone and then changing the parentId on the cloned record. It worked for FeedItem , but the same did not work for FeedComment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [schema doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feedcomment.htm) is explicit here - you can't insert or update `FeedComment.ParentId`

> **Type** reference

> **Properties** Filter, Group, Nillable, Sort

> **Description**
> ID of a record associated with the feed comment. For example, if you are commenting on a change to a field on Account, ParentId is set to the account ID.

This is telling you that `ParentId` is a derived (formula) field

Instead, you need to set the `clonedFeedComment's` `FeedItemId` to the cloned `FeedItem`

You'll need to use a Map to cross reference the source FeedComment to the cloned, inserted FeedItems.

Answer (score 1):

Remove below line from your code I faced same issue :

```
feedCommentClone.ParentId = cloneObj.Id;
```